# Java Thread synchronized getCoon

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a list of free sockets conn, and i put then in a Map , if status of free or inUse, but the synchronized dosent seens to be working correctly
this is my code:
my map is like this:

`private ConcurrentHashMap<MVConnection, Boolean> listaConn = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`

my connManager is this:

```
public synchronized MVConnection getInstance() {
    System.out.println("pass here on  getInstance");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Before request Instance");
    LogLinhas();
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    MVConnection searchResult = null;
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is running");
    while (searchResult == null) {
        searchResult = this.listaConn.search(1, (conn, free) -> {
            if (free) {
                return conn;
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
    notify();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " notifying");
    if (searchResult != null) {
        this.listaConn.replace(searchResult, false);
        try {
            System.out.println("Set " + searchResult.getServerPort() + " as busy");
        } catch (MVException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("After request Instance");
    LogLinhas();
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    return searchResult;
}
```

and the function the request the cont is this:

```
public abstract class AbstractD3Dao<T extends Serializable> {
@Autowired
ConexaoD3 conexao;
protected MVConnection getCurrentSession() {
System.out.println("Abstract request the conn");
MVConnection connPool = null;
    synchronized (conexao.getInstance()) {
        while (connPool == null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Aguardando Conexao");
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is waiting");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connPool = conexao.getInstance();
            }
    }

    try {
        System.out.println(" Abstract assineg the PIB " + connPool.getServerPort() + "to use");
    } catch (MVException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connPool;
}
```

`

Comment: Only immutable objects can be keys in a Map.  Is your MVConnection immutable?

Comment: Yes, the object is allways the same.. when i use without the thread hi works fine